# .htaccess RedirectMatch 301 issue

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, redirects, 301-redirect

I've moved my WordPress installation from one domain to another, and I want to use an .htaccess file on the original to redirect visitors to the new page on the new website.

The old site is `http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/`.

The new site is `http://www.superlogical.net`

I tried using tried using the following .htaccess file in the `/wordpress` directory:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress(.*) http://www.superlogical.net/$1
```

However, all this does is redirect visitors to the URL: `http://www.superlogical.net/wordpress/`

I guess this is working properly, but I don't have Wordpress installed in a `/wordpress` folder on the new domain.  How do I remove this from the URL redirected to?

Comment: The `RedirectMatch` directive matches against a root-relative (starting with a slash) URL-path, not the absolute URL, so the above directive would not have done _anything_ - it would not have matched. Even it did match, it wouldn't have redirected to the `/wordpress` folder - so there must have been _something else_ going on here. Incidentally, 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so it's quite possible you were seeing a cached response. It's often best to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `/wordpress/.htaccess` file, I changed it to the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.superlogical.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you’re using regexp on the second parameter you want to escape the dots. Change

```
http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress(.*)
```

to

```
http://www\.steve\.doig\.com\.au/wordpress(.*)
```

The logic itself, how you meant it, should work though. Passing the following URL-part to the new URL.

Comment: Thanks.  It successfully redirects from the /wordpress folder of the old website, but I receive a page not found error when I try to load the URL of an individual wordpress post on the old site.  The browser still has the old URL in the address bar, indicating it has not tried to redirect the page.  Do I need to include an .htaccess file in every content folder?

Comment: .htaccess files will apply to the directory it is in as well as all sub-directories. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#what

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, but this doesn't change the fact it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told by my webhost to try the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?steve\.doig\.com\.au/wordpress/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.superlogical.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this only works for the /wordpress folder, and not for any post or category page.

Comment: This shouldn't have worked at all. The `/wordpress/` URL-path is not part of the `HTTP_HOST` variable, so the _condition_ would have failed, preventing the redirect?